# SmartGWT ComboBoxItem get all Records

Tags: java, smartgwt

How can I get all Records from a SmartGWT ComboBoxItem?

I add the Records as a Datasource. Did not found any way to retrive all Records.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
RecordList recordList=comboBoxItem.getValueAsRecordList();

Record[] records=recordList.getRange(0, recordList.getLength());
```

Answer (score 0):

RecodList support toArray method to get all records.

```
RecordList recordList=comboBoxItem.getValueAsRecordList();

recordList.toArray()
```