# How to get all options of a comboBoxItem in smart gwt

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I don't think this is correct [Same Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337604/smartgwt-comboboxitem-get-all-records)

```
.getOptionDataSource().getCacheData()
```

also doesn't work. I'm referring to a databound comboBoxitem

Answer (score 1):

You must set

```
setCacheAllData(Boolean.TRUE);
```

in order to retrieve the cached data via `DataSource.getCacheData()`.

But please note that that is only useful if you're sure that the corresponding DataSource is already fetched (also keep [CACHE-MAX-AGE](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/data/DataSource.html#setCacheMaxAge-int-) in mind).

Especially for larger amounts of data, or when you [fetch the data on opening the ComboBox](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/SelectItem.html#setAutoFetchData-java.lang.Boolean-), I would rather recommend to use

```
.getOptionDataSource().fetchData(Criteria , Callback)
```

where you could access the data in the `Callback`.

Comment: I'll check this out and let know. But how to find these info. Because there is no proper documentation for such type of scenarios. Google also doesn't help. Is there any proper documentation i can refer in such situations? Thanks

Comment: And if you know a proper way for following problem please let me know. I'd really appreciate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406929/smart-gwt-comboboxitem-deosnt-filter-based-on-user-input

Comment: If you would prefer some full text over javadoc, you could use the [Quick Start Guide](http://www.smartclient.com/releases/SmartGWT_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf)